# How to add a hint into Bar Button Item about purpose of button?

Tags: ios, swift, toolbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am using BarButtonItem in toolbar and I set an image into BarButtonItem.
But I want user to know what is purpose of this Button. I want to set a hint about it and User can see a text when Press hold on Bar Button.
Is it possible to do that set some members of bar button item?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly add something like that by displaying a subview triggered by a long press gesture recognizer.

The problem is usability. If someone holds down a button to see the message, they'll probably just let go of the button after they read it, and if they don't move away from the button first, they'll inadvertently trigger it. If, instead, you decide that if they see the message you'll ignore the button press, that's an awkward non-standard iOS user experience.

The Apple Human Interface Guidelines should lead you to creating a UI that's fairly intuitive so you won't normally need to do something like this. Also, mobile software has a user "explorability" component to it. If users don't know what something does, they'll try it and then know afterwards. Having a message that pops up would only be beneficial before that first exploration, and it would actually delay them getting to it, which isn't a great customer experience.

If something really warrants explanation, consider creating a swipe-through tour or coach mark overlay images that describe the functionality of the screen. Either can be presented the first time the user lands on a view and then hidden unless the user wants to bring them back.

So, yes, it's possible, but it really doesn't fit with iOS app design. I'd focus on the problem you want to solve, rather than this particular solution.

Comment: Thanks for your guides. This will be my first ios app experience. I think like you said app tour is more suitable than. Thanks for your help.